# Custom model field in Django | Using both integerchoice and textarea

Tags: django, model, field

I'm trying to create a model that contains more than 50 fields.
Each field has 4 other fields:

1. IntegerChoice
2. Reason for that choice
3. Another IntegerChoice
4. Reason for that choice

I think that a custom model field to solve this is the best option, but i'm not sure if this is the way to go?
I would be following the official documentation to implement this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/
as mentioned I'm not 100% convinced it's the best way to go to make this code DRY?

Example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    consequence_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    c_description_1 = models.TextField()
    likelihood_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    l_description_1 = models.TextField()
    
    consequence_2 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    c_description_2 = models.TextField()
    likelihood_2 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    l_description_2 = models.TextField()

    .......

    consequence_50 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    c_description_50 = models.TextField()
    likelihood_50 = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    l_description_50 = models.TextField()
```

I've been looking into creating a Model for the field and linking it with OneToOneField, but this really complicates the automated forms in Django that i would like to use.

```
class MyFieldModel(models.Model):
    consequence = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    c_description = models.TextField()
    likelihood = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 6), range(1, 6))))
    l_description = models.TextField()

class MyNewModel(models.Model):
    field_1 =  models.OneToOneField(MyFieldModel, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    field_2 =  models.OneToOneField(MyFieldModel, on_delete =models.CASCADE)

    .......

    field_50 =  models.OneToOneField(MyFieldModel, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
```

While this shortens the models length down from ~200 fields to 54 fields it doesn't seem like the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Based on  the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#module-django.db.models):

> Each attribute of the model represents a database field.

To satisfy the first normal form (1NF) of the database we should keep the field atomic. Having just one field containing multiple values of multiple types is not a good idea IMHO.

A better way of handling this complex model would be to use the `composition` pattern. By applying the pattern, we should extract out the fields which are common in the subject in your domain into new models. Then, connect them by defining new relations with the main model (currently, the one with more than 50 fields).

Comment: I agree that on the database level it should be saved as    
field1_IntegerChoice1
field1_reason1
field1_IntegerChoice2
field1_reason2

Composite like this?  https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite/python/example

Comment: `Composition` like this: https://stackify.com/oop-concepts-composition/. Let's have an example of the `Car`. A `Car` itself may have a lot of attributes. One approach is having all of these attributes in a single Model which leads `Car` to become a God class. The other approach is to group some of these fields into smaller Models, like ‍‍`EngineDetails` or `BrakeDateils`. Then the `Car` itself will have two new fields of `engine_details` and `brake_details` which are just foreign keys to the newly implemented Models.

Comment: I'm not sure my problem is the same as the one you mention with the car, even though i see where you are going. I've updated my question with examples and I would appreciate it if you had the time to take a look at it again.